# Hover doesn't go away when you mouse out in <= IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have encountered an interesting issue I could not find posted elsewhere.

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPXWS/2/).  I have a div that has 2 things occur when you hover over it:  (1)  It gains some CSS formatting via the :hover pseudo class, and (2) an overlay with some information about the image pops up on the bottom of the image (via jQuery).

This works just fine in all the modern browsers, but open it up in IE 7 or 8.  Mouseover the frame.  If you mouseout over the top of the frame, there are no problems -- the overlay disappears and the CSS formatting gets removed.  But if your mouse passes directly over the overlay while you're mousing out, the :hover formatting stays.  jQuery knows that you moused out because the overlay gets removed, but IE doesn't because the CSS :hover formatting remains.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you are already using jQuery for hover, I recommend changing your script to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frame').hover(
        function() {
            $('#frame').addClass('hover').append('<div id="overlay">blah blah</div>');
        }, 
        function() {
             $('#frame').removeClass('hover')
            $('#overlay').remove();
        }
    );
});
```

And then change your CSS from `:hover` to `.hover` on all relevant elements. As per this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BZj2v/

Comment: This is a viable solution,  but I think my solution better addresses his question,  as it begins with him implying that he was curious about the issue.  This is a good workaround though (p.s. Sorry about the accidental down vote -  I'm  on mobile -  I undid it)

Comment: I did actually try mouseleave and enter first, but it didn't work on my fiddle. Are you sure it works? IE7 still didn't like it

Comment: See my solution - I just updated it with your updated fiddle and with the code

Answer (score 5):

CSS `:hover` support for all elements except **link `<a>..</a>`** is incomplete/not supported for IE < 8.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16

> IE 5/6 supports both only on links. IE 7 supports :hover, but not :active, on all elements.
>
> IE 8-10 (and maybe older ones, too) have a slight bug: clicking the mouse down on a nested element does not trigger :active. Try it in the test page by depressing the mouse button on one of the code examples. The :active styles do not kick in.

Comment: So you think there's no way to fix this issue?  I can refactor my code to move the formatting out of CSS and into jQuery .hover events.  I was trying to avoid doing so, because this refactoring will not be the simplest task to do, but if there's no other solution, I guess I'll have to.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

This is a widely known happening in jQuery,  resulting from the fact that internet explorer's mouse leave function is proprietary. You will need to use jquery's mouseleave/mouseenter methods.

Here is your <strike>[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPXWS/3/)</strike> **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPXWS/6/)** with the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` methods. It works and has been tested in IE7-9.

For sake of ease, I am including the code here, as well:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frame').mouseenter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.append('<div id="overlay">blah blah</div>');
        $this.addClass("hover");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });
    $('#overlay').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#frame {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
#frame.hover {
    border:1px solid red;
}
#frame img {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=25);
    -moz-opacity: 0.25;
    opacity: 0.25;
}
#frame.hover img {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
#overlay {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
    font-size:10px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I have updated my fiddle and the code above, based on the results you described in your comment. It should fully work - please let me know if it does not.

**A little more detail:**

This solution uses jQuery's `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods because of a multitude of issues that IE has with the `hover` method. As you may or may not know, `hover` is a shorthand version of `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`, but there are dozens of issues with the `hover` method, stemming all the way from IE6-9 (and possibly IE 10, though I have not tested this). For some of the specific issues, search Stack Overflow or Google for "jQuery hover IE issues" and look at some of the results that come up. For this reason, I always take the extra ten seconds to type `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` rather than using `hover`, especially when I'm already running into issues with my code in IE.

Let me know if you have any questions/difficulties. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately it doesn't exactly work, though.  The reason it appears to fix the issue is that when you mouse out over the overlay, you pass over the red border (part of the frame div).  If you pass over the frame div, then the bug doesn't show up.  Try your fiddle but mouse out very quickly over the overlay.  The red border will stay if the mouse position doesn't register on the border as it passes over.  Here is a better JFiddle to demonstrate this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kPXWS/2/

Comment: Nathan, I have updated my solution with both the updated fiddle (which fixes the issues you described in your comment), and the updated code and CSS. I urge you to read the section "A little more detail", as you may be opening the door to bigger issues if you move forward with jQuery's `hover` method.

Comment: As a side note, I would like to point out that this post is nearly a month old, and I responded to your newly discovered issue within an hour of you alerting me to it. In the future, before un-accepting a solution to an old question and accepting one with different code, give the person you originally credited some time to take a look at the problem. I chose the methods in my code carefully and for a specific reason - the solution you recently accepted is an easy way to cause more issues.